# Azure DevOps deploy overwrites not always cshtml files

Tags: razor, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-tasks

Sometimes it happens that when we do a deploy, the last committed files with extension cshtml, are not updated. We have not seen other type files being not updated. It could be that a file is in use and can't be overwrited. Is it possible to add an extra step to the deployment process so we can avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is strange. If you are using the Azure App Service Deploy task within Azure Pipelines to deploy to your Web App, you have the option to **Remove additional files at destination**. Enabling this option deletes files in the Azure App Service that have no matching files in the App Service artifact package or folder being deployed.

Based on the [chosen deployment method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops#deployment-methods), there are other helpful additional deployment options like:

- **Rename locked files:** Rename any file that is still in use by the web server by enabling the msdeploy flag `MSDEPLOY_RENAME_LOCKED_FILES=1` in the Azure App Service settings. This option, if set, enables msdeploy to rename files that are locked during app deployment. This way, you can avoid deployment failures with `ERROR_FILE_IN_USE` errors.
- **Take App Offline:** Select this option to take the Azure App Service offline by placing an `app_offline.htm` file in the root directory before the synchronization operation begins. The file will be removed after the synchronization completes successfully.

[image: Additional Deployment Options]

Having these in place can streamline your deployments and make them robust. Here is the complete reference for the task: [Azure App Service Deploy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops).